# Want to get a user who uploaded the product in the order model schema mongo db mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a product schema in which user(who uploaded ,created the product) is there who creates a product and then there is an order , order schema has the product included , I want it to include the products uploader user . Can anyone help me to do that ? I really hope i make it clear enough it's haunting me for days and I have searched the internet

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    shippingInfo: {
        address: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        phoneNo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        postalCode: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        country: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    orderItems: [
        {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            image: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            price: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            product: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: true,
                ref: 'Product'
            },
            
        }
    ],
    paymentInfo: {
        id: {
            type: String
        },
        status: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    paidAt: {
        type: Date
    },

    itemsPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    taxPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    shippingPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    orderStatus: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'Processing'
    },
    deliveredAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)
```

this is my product Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product name'],
        trim: true,
        maxLength: [100, 'Product name cannot exceed 100 characters']
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product price'],
        maxLength: [5, 'Product name cannot exceed 5 characters'],
        default: 0.0
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product description'],
    },
    ratings: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    images: [
        {
            public_id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            url: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
        }
    ],
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select category for this product'],
        enum: {
            values: [
                'Electronics',
                'Cameras',
                'Laptops',
                'Accessories',
                'Headphones',
                'Food',
                "Books",
                'Clothes/Shoes',
                'Beauty/Health',
                'Sports',
                'Outdoor',
                'Home'
            ],
            message: 'Please select correct category for product'
        }
    },
    seller: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product seller']
    },
    stock: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product stock'],
        maxLength: [5, 'Product name cannot exceed 5 characters'],
        default: 0
    },
    numOfReviews: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    reviews: [
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User',
                required: true
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            rating: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            comment: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ],
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },

    
    
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

this is my user Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const crypto = require('crypto')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your name'],
        maxLength: [30, 'Your name cannot exceed 30 characters']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your email'],
        unique: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter valid email address']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your password'],
        minlength: [6, 'Your password must be longer than 6 characters'],
        select: false
    },
    avatar: {
        public_id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        url: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date

})

// Encrypting password before saving user
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
        next()
    }

    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)
})

// Compare user password
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password)
}

// Return JWT token
userSchema.methods.getJwtToken = function () {
    return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_TIME
    });
}

// Generate password reset token
userSchema.methods.getResetPasswordToken = function () {
    // Generate token
    const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');

    // Hash and set to resetPasswordToken
    this.resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(resetToken).digest('hex')

    // Set token expire time
    this.resetPasswordExpire = Date.now() + 30 * 60 * 1000

    return resetToken

}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: You can populate product and then from the product populate the user,you need to use deep population

Comment: ` Order.find(any order).populate([
{
      path: 'orderItems.product',
      model: 'Order',
      populate: [
        {
          path: 'user',
          model: 'User',
          select: 'name',
        },
      ],
    },

]) `
Note: you can edit it for correct paths

Comment: I think  you are not getting what I am saying  bro I simply just want  to get products user , in the order  , i have products integrated  in the order model but in the order model i want to get creater of the product which is already there in product model

Comment: this is already in product model                                                                                                               ```                                                                                                                                                                   user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },                                                                                                                                                                                     ```

Comment: i want to have it in order model  product  is already added  in there but want to add the user of the product . this is from my order Schema i have the product added their but want to add products user ,                        product: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: true,
                ref: 'Product'
            },

Comment: Can you tell me why exactly do you want to do with the user? do you want to store it in the order or just want to show it on your front end?

Comment: can u help me on that please I can pay you ?

Comment: the schema is uploaded above too

Comment: can you please contact me ? bro ?

Comment: my number is right up there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Order.find(any order).populate([ { path: 'orderItems.product', model: 'Order', populate: [ { path: 'user', model: 'User', select: 'name', }, ], }, ]) ` Note: you can edit it for correct paths
```